# COM Port of USB Mouse?

Tags: windows-vista, usb, port

I plugged in a USB mouse into my Vista machine and it's working fine. Is this device assigned a COM port number? If so, how do I determine it?

In Device Manager, under Ports, everything listed there is either prefixed with a "Bluetooth Serial Port (COMxx)" or "BT Port (COMxx)". Nothing there to suggest the com port of the mouse. I see the mouse under "Mice and other pointing devices", but looking at the properties of the mouse does not reveal the com port number.

I'm curious because I'm interested in using a programming library I found that allows me to read and send messages to a com port device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, USB mice do not emulate serial port. They use USB HID device class shared with keyboards and drawing pads.
BT mice also do not use any of serial ports, they use HID channel.

Comment: How can I get a device on my laptop assigned a COM port? All I have are USB ports. Would really like to play with this library.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=usb+to+serial+adapter is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking. USB mice sometimes *do* do PS/2 but those arn't conventional serial ports either

Comment: Are there any hardware that might emulate a COM port? It doesn't need to be a mouse.

Comment: Yes - called USB serial port adapter.
Your serial port library has no effect on USB ports, you can use it though against modem in mobile phone etc. For USB you need USB library like libusb or so.
You might want to use UNIX, since half of devices are character devices - good enough to be serial port for serial port libraries.